# MFC trigger ID_FILE_OPEN command

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a standard SDI app in MFC and I would like to trigger the standard File->Open for opening a document from a user button.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: I tried to send a `ID_FILE_OPEN` message to my MainFrame, did not work. Tried calling `CWinAppEx::OnFileOpen` but it is protected.

Comment: I believe the message you need to send is `WM_COMMAND`, with `ID_FILE_OPEN` as a parameter. The details may be a bit off, but that might get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to invoke the predefined File->Open action, post this message:

```
AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_OPEN, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You’ll need to design your button handler code to create an instance of the [CFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh5hz49d(v=vs.120).aspx) class.  Make sure to set the appropriate flags when you construct the object.  Then call its DoModal method.  If you need more control, you can derive your own class from CFileDialog.  You should be able to search and find plenty of examples.

Comment: You can add this to `MainFrame` message map: `ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OPEN, onfileopen)` then define `onfileopen()` `CFileDialog dlg(TRUE, ...); if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK) MessageBox(dlg.GetFileName());`