# MFC MDI ID_FILE_OPEN Non override, but use the variable for status message

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, mfc

Preface: I have an MFC MDI using the wizard in VS2017 to create the project...it works without issue.

Goal: To use the ID_FILE_OPEN to execute normal document creation without modification but use the same ID to trigger my own function in parallel to write to the output tab at the bottom.

So here is what is happening. When I select file>open from the menu or toolbar button, the file open dialog works as I expect and docs open normally. What I want to do is fire my own function that writes a status message of "File Open Process" in the status output window tab. What I am finding is that even with the message map that uses the ID_FILE_OPEN ID with my unique function (that does work with other IDs that are not system bound) when I debug it and I call the open command, the file dialog opens, but it never enters my unique function to simply write the "File Open Process" string to the output pane. I read about overriding the default handler for this particular variable here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class?view=msvc-160#onfileopen

I don't want to change that or have to rewrite the file open dialog since it is already handled by the framework, all I want to do is track the ID_FILE_OPEN and have it trigger my function to write the status message for the user. It seems I can do one or the other, but not both at the same time? So below is what my message map looks like and my function, is there a way to track the ID_FILE_OPEN so I can have it do both as I expect?

The message

In my Application.cpp:

I've tried....

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OPEN, CWinApp::OnFileOpenMe)
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OPEN, &CWinApp::OnFileOpenMe)
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OPEN, OnFileOpenMe)


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CApplication, CWinAppEx)
  ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OPEN, OnFileOpen)
  ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OPEN, CWinApp::OnFileOpenMe)  // << This never fires even with &CwinApp
  ON_COMMAND(ID_APP_ABOUT, OnAppAbout)
  ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_WINDOW_NEW, DisableNewWindowMenuItem) 
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

The status message function in Application.cpp that works with other IDs but is never called from the message map using ID_FILE_OPEN ID:

```
    void CApplication::OnFileOpenMe()
{
    CMainFrame* pMainFrame = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();
    pMainFrame->m_wndOutput.AddStringStatusTab(_T("File Open Process"));
}
```

Here is prototype in Application.h

```
class CApplication : public CWinAppEx
{
protected:
    .......... //More message above omitted 
    afx_msg void DisableNewWindowMenuItem(CCmdUI *ppkCmdUI);
    afx_msg void OnFileOpenMe();
}
```

Comment: [TN022: Standard Commands Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn022-standard-commands-implementation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a a more elegant way to handle this without compromising the solution and default framework.

Using this post here:

[MFC trigger ID_FILE_OPEN command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133289/mfc-trigger-id-file-open-command)

I've reformed the message map:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CApplication, CWinAppEx)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OPEN, OnFileOpen) // Leave active, not used, needed to keep control active to call open
    ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_BRANCH_OPEN, OnFileBranchOpen)

END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

I changed the ID on the ID_FILE_OPEN to ID_FILE_BRANCH_OPEN in all the menu and buttons that used to call ID_FILE_OPEN.

Using the thread I listed above my function now looks like:

```
void CApplication::OnFileBranchOpen()
{       
    CMainFrame* pMainFrame = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();
    pMainFrame->m_wndOutput.AddStringStatusTab(_T("File Open Process"));
    AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_OPEN, 0); // Open File Open Dialog and load
}
```

Note that the ID_FILE_OPEN remains in the message map even if unused/called, my understanding is that it leaves the framework call function/handling in tact while using my new menu ID to trigger the Open File Dialog framework call while also processing my status message as my original intent.

I'm hoping that this may help someone in the future and show a different way to make this work when dealing with system reserved message mappings.

If any of my description of what I did needs clarification, please feel free to add your comments.

Thanks for reading.